# Clicking code of conduct link raises flag

Tags: bug, android-app

When raising a flag on a comment, two of the options contain a blue underlined code of conduct link. Trying to click the link irreversibly raises the flag under that category.

[image]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Google
- Device Model: Pixel
- OS Version: 8.1.0 (4820305)

Comment: I normally would try that myself, but that would mean some poor user gets undeserved flags. Can you show screenshots? Have the upvoters already experienced this themselves? (This is not criticising or doubting, just stating and asking for more info.)

Comment: There's not much to take a screenshot of. Here is the flag menu for your comment. If I press the code of conduct link, it will flag your message (I didn't do that this time). https://photos.app.goo.gl/qf2tXzaYbta9hCNRA

Comment: The screenshot is very helpful and convinces me that it cannot be intentional. I would expect a radio button allowing for clickable links to COC. (As I see them in desktop Opera by the way.)

Comment: Thankfully, comment flags don't count towards flag bans.

Comment: It'll be fixed in 6 to 8 <arbitrary units of time>.

Comment: mehhh app. Isn't that abbandoned 6 to 8 <arbitrary units of time> ago?

Comment: You'd think we'd have received an official response at this point. It's not like this could be making people flag unwillingly left and right until they fix this, creating many false flags that can either get the flagger unable to flag more, or the flaggee banned.

Comment: I find this issue insanely ironic.

Answer (score 27):

This is an issue because each of those choices and their text (including the link) is in a `<label>` element.

[There is a relevant question/answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755802/a-link-inside-a-label-also-triggers-the-checkbox-how-to-prevent) about resolving this.

Of course, the people at SO have to do this :)

Comment: This is in the Android app, not the website, but the same general principles apply here.

Comment: A problem on SO fixed by the content on SO. Marvelous!